# How do you create an application with a unique GUI like Valve's Steam?

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi, api, graphics

Valve's game manager application, Steam, has a very unique user interface, with custom buttons and windows.  How would you create a Win32 application that has such a look?

Comment: Why? I really thought that steam was a shining example of why skinned apps were bad. Its a horrible horrible looking app that could be improved in almost every way if it was rewritten to use the OSs look n feel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much every windows common control supports custom and/or owner draw (not the exact same thing), that just leaves the dialog itself where you can customize its look by handling WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT or WM_NCCALCSIZE,WM_NCPAINT (If you don't want native titlebars and border etc)

As you can see, to do a custom GUI requires you to paint every control yourself... (And keep in mind that a lot of people hate skinned apps and would rather just have a native looking app)

Comment: Related to this answer, I'd recommend reading this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/SkinWindowWithWin32API.aspx